# What language is required when learning Selendroid?

Tags: selenium, java, mobile, android

I want to learn [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/).

I do not know what language I need to know before starting with selendroid.
I know selenium using Java.
For selendroid, do I have to learn android?

Answer (score 1):

There is no programming language called Android. Android is an OS and that as well is developed with Java(I Guess).

You can learn and use Selendroid using Java. For Java you will get a lot of help from the countless communities and forums on the internet and is completely open source.

Since you are already using Selenium Webdriver with Java, I guess it'll be easier for you to get your hands on Selendroid as well.

There are also several other programming languages that you can use, but for you using Java will be more advantageous as you have experience with Java and Selenium!

Happy Testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can start selenium using java programming language. , Helpful tutorial you can find below :

[Selenium web driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Selenium support many programming languages like Java , c# , Python and some others also. It will help you to do automation testing for functionalists. For ex: Login , Register in website.

To start with selendroid , you do not need to learn android. Selenium web driver is enough.